# How to get character level difference using "diff" command in Linux using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, diff

I have two SQL files, one is `old.sql` and the other one is `new.sql`.

Suppose `old.sql` contains a table with three fields, Emp_Id, Name and Address and data stored in old.sql as follows:

```
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", "xyz");
Insert into table1 values (102 ,"b", "pqr");
```

Then I have changed "a" address "xyz" to "xyz123" and saved that data in the `new.sql` file.
Now the `new.sql` file contains data as follows:

```
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", "xyz123");
Insert into table1 values (102 ,"b", "pqr");
```

When I use the `diff` command like this:

```
diff old.sql new.sql
```

it gives differences line-wise but I want only updated data, like xyz123.

Answer (score 17):

Short answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356602/819417):

`git diff --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2`

And [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314510/16521):

`diff -u file1 file2 |perl /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight`

Comment: The first command is a true character-by-character comparison

Comment: A small tip for the git example above: Add `--no-index` and you can diff untracked files as well.

Answer (score 9):

You might find [`wdiff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/) useful for this type of comparison; it's a front-end to `diff` which produces word-by-word comparisons. With your example it produces by default

```
Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a", [-"xyz");-] {+"xyz123");+}
Insert into table1 values (102 ,"b", "pqr");
```

It can use terminal features to make the output more legible on a terminal (`wdiff -t`). It also has a `-3` option which limits output to changed words only:

```
======================================================================
 [-"xyz");-] {+"xyz123");+}
======================================================================
```

If you don't have wdiff already installed, you need to install it. Run `sudo apt-get install wdiff` or `sudo dnf install wdiff` or `sudo yum install wdiff` or the command that is appropriate to your operating system.

Comment: but when I use wdiff command instead of diff command prompt is showing error wdiff command not found

Comment: @user168519 that simply means you need to install it, `sudo apt-get install wdiff` or `sudo dnf install wdiff` or `sudo yum install wdiff` or your local equivalent.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I have installed wdiff but it is not comparing data present  inside the parenthesis.

Comment: @user168519 that's odd, could you edit your question to show `wdiff`'s behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
diff -u old.sql new.sql |colordiff |diff-highlight
```

[image: screenshot]

colordiff is a Ubuntu package. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install colordiff`.

`diff-hight` is from git (since version 2.9). It is located in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight`. You can put it somewhere in your `$PATH`. Or get it from [diff-so-fancy project](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/tree/master/third_party/diff-highlight).

Answer (score 2):

By definition, diff is showing differences lines by lines (see diff manual page), it will therefore not show only the differing characters.
You can reduce the amount of difference by pre-processing the files, for exemple by inserting an end-of-line character after each semi-column:

```
sed -e 's/;/;\'$'\n/g' old.sql > old.patched
```

Then use diff on the two resulting files.

Comment: This might not be a great idea unless you can guarantee there's nothing like:

    Insert into table1 values (101 ,"a;", "xyz;");

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote my [own script](https://github.com/JEdward7777/JLDiff/blob/master/JLDiff.py) to solve this problem using the [Longest common subsequence algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

It is executed as such

```
JLDiff.py a.txt b.txt out.html
```

The result is in html with red and green coloring. Larger files do exponentially take a longer amount of time to process but this does a true character-by-character comparison without checking line by line first.

This answer is cross-posted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40919814).

I have found that JLDiff runs a lot faster under pypy.