# How to generate (git) diffs with <n> characters of context?

Tags: command-line, scripting, git, colors, diff

The [`--unified=<n>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---unifiedltngt) option lets you set the number of lines; is there a way to do the same for characters?

**example**

limit the context around the changes to X character(s) when using `git diff --color-words=. file.ext`

**special case to take into account**

a change is within the context of the previous and/or next change

**use case**

diffing a minified file containing one long line

**TL;DR**

I want to snip everything in the line except the changes and their context.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286601/7579

Comment: To be honest, I missed the point of you question. Do you really want a solution supporting colours?

Comment: Knu, never mind, updated answer should satisfy needs.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do the job, at least as long escape sequences (for colouring) are as expected. Call it e.g. as `git-diff-word-context -U 5`. It accepts all arguments `git diff` would accept and intercepts `-U` (respectively `--unified=`) to set the number of characters.
It just utilises `grep` to fulfil the task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ESCAPE=$'\e'
START_DIFF="$ESCAPE\\[3[12]m"
END_DIFF="$ESCAPE\\[m"
NOESCAPE="[^$ESCAPE]"

CONTEXT="20"
STDIN=false
ARGS=()
while [ "${1::1}" = "-" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        "-U"|"--unified")
            CONTEXT="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        "-U"*)
            CONTEXT="${1#-U}"
            ;;
        "--unified="*)
            CONTEXT="${1#--unified=}"
            ;;
        "--stdin")
            STDIN=true
            ;;
        "--")
            break
            ;;
        *)
            ARGS+=("$1")
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

set -o pipefail

ok() {
    "$@"
    true
}

if $STDIN; then
    cat
else
    git diff --color-words='[^\n]' "${ARGS[@]}" "$@"
fi |
ok grep -oP "$NOESCAPE{0,$CONTEXT}(($START_DIFF[^$ESCAPE]+$END_DIFF)+$NOESCAPE{0,$CONTEXT})+"
```

The easiest way to call it is to configure a Git alias e.g. with `git config alias.diffwc '!path/to/git-diff-word-context'`.

You can also use it as a filter call it with option `--stdin`, for example `git show --color-words | git-diff-word-context --stdin -U5`.

To configure it as an external diff driver, you need to take additional measures (refer to `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` within `man git`). Passing arbitrary arguments to `git diff` is IMHO especially difficult in that case.

#### Example

[image: example output]

Comment: My BSD grep 2.5.1 doesn't have a `P` option so `git-diff-word-context -U 5 file.ext` failed.

Comment: It is quite easy to convert the used Perl regular expression to POSIX confirming ones. Please state your requirements in your question.

Comment: You seem to use FreeBSD, is this correct? ("This option is not supported in FreeBSD.") It is hard to find a solution without knowledge of constraints.

Comment: This is the line without Perl regular expressions: `ok grep -o ".\\{0,$CONTEXT\\}\\($START_DIFF[^$ESCAPE]\\+$END_DIFF\\)\\+.\\{0,$CONTEXT\\}"`

Comment: I tried the version "without Perl regular expressions" and it doesn't diff at a char level: it's not as granular as `--color-words=.`.

Comment: "You seem to use FreeBSD, is this correct?" I am not. I am using macOS X

Comment: The solution is generic enough. You can just tell Git what a word ist. Have a look at option `--word-diff-regex` for `git diff` and friends.

Comment: To be more specific: `For example, --word-diff-regex=.  will treat each character as a word and, correspondingly, show differences character by character.`

Comment: Knu, I added two characters to the script to fullfill the by character requirement.

Comment: To be honest, I would limit words to not cross lines (i.e. to use `--color-words='[^\n]'`) instead. I just used `.` in the updated answer because you did the same in your question, thus I imply it's your intention.

Comment: Alright it's almost there. I just need to replace the separator (`\n`) by something custom. BTW I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: You already can do. Just call the script like this: `git-diff-word-context --color-words=<arg>`. This will overwrite script default. The script just passes all arguments to `git diff` with the exception of `-U`. Or you use it as a filter: `git show HEAD~5 --color-words=<arg> | git-diff-word-context`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89692/discussion-between-doak-and-knu).

Comment: In response to chat:
You did not mention any separator, but implied coloured output in your question.
In fact the solutions works like asked. I am out.

Comment: It's totally impractical to use `\n` as the separator when you have tons of changes. Just append `| sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ … /g'`. Note that wouldn't work with the BSD sed though.